# Python request CloudFlare

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, cloudflare

I send the request to https://example.org:

```
def get_item(request):

     dominio = request.GET.get('item')

     payload = {'item': item}

     url = '{0}item/'.format(settings.API_URL)

     try:
         r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
     except:
         raise Exception('Ops,error')

     if r.status_code == 404:
        raise Exception('Not found')

     return r.json()
```

I use Cloudflare to redirect to https://example.

But https cloudflare block my request. How solved?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
requests.get(url, params=payload)
```

to

```
requests.get(url, params=payload, verify=False)
```